# Blocks not present in layout

Tags: layout, cms

I'm using the CMS to display the product list block on my homepage via this markup in the CMS editor

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" mode="grid" name="home.catalog.product.list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column="one_column" size="small"}}
```

I wanted to add additional blocks beneath it, however the blocks from that markup don't end up in the layout? Using [Alan Storm's Layoutviewer](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates) module to inspect the layout the block I'm looking for (with name *home.catalog.product.list*) doesn't show in the output.

Considering that Alan's module is somehow missing elements added by the CMS, I went ahead and tried to add the blocks I'm after via *Custom Layout Update XML* under *Design* in the CMS editor for the homepage:

```
<reference name="home.catalog.product.list">
    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</reference>
```

The pager markup isn't added to the page though, probably because the *home.catalog.product.list* block isn't in the layout... But how is that possible, the markup for the *catalog/product_list* block is on the homepage, it's just not present in the layout (that I can tell).

My question - why isn't the block I'm adding from the CMS showing up in the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you cannot define a block name when dynamically adding a block via the block directive.

The Filter class to generate a Block from the block directive in cms content is declared here: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Template/Filter.php

It is extended from the Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter.

If you look at the blockDirective method, it just passes null as the name for the block: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php#L179

This results in a anonymous block beeing created (I think it gets a random name somewhere): https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L443

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a hacky way of adding the block in a template that's working right now, but I'd prefer to figure out how to do it using a layout update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use the attribute "name_in_layout"?

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" mode="grid" name="home.catalog.product.list" name_in_layout="home.catalog.product.list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column="one_column" size="small"}}
```